# kubectl rollout restart deployment <deployment-name> doesn't get the latest image

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Why does `kubectl rollout restart <deployment-name>` doesn't get my latest image? I had rebuild my image but it seems that kubernetes doesn't update my deployment with the latest image.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

I just wanted to add an answer here regarding the failure of `kubectl rollout restart deployment [my-deployment-name]`. My problem was that I **changed the image name**, without running `kubectl apply -f [my-deployment-filename>.yaml` first.

## Long Answer

So my earlier image name is `microservices/posts` which is in my local and looked like this.

```yaml
# This is a file named `posts-depl.yaml`
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: posts-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: posts
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: posts
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: posts
          image: microservices/posts
```

However, since I need to push it to Docker Hub, I rebuild the image with a new name of `[my docker hub username]/microservices_posts` then I pushed. Then I updated the `posts-depl.yaml` to look like this.

```yaml
# Still same file `posts-depl.yaml` but updated
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: posts-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: posts
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: posts
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: posts
          image: [my docker hub username]/microservices_posts # Notice that I only change this part
```

Apparently, when I ran `kubectl rollout restart deployment posts-depl`, it didn't update. Then I finally decided to go to StackOverflow. I just thought I had a wrong mistake or probably meet up with kubernetes bug or something.

But turns out I had to run `kubectl apply -f <your deployment filename>.yaml` again. Then it's running fine.

Just sharing, might change someone's life. ;)

**So for a review here..**

It seems that my past deployment which is `posts-depl` is cached with the image name of my earlier image which is `microservices/posts`, and since I build a new image named `[my docker hub username]/microservices_posts` it doesn't acknowledge that. So when I run `kubectl rollout restart deployment <deployment name>`. What it does instead was looking for the `microservices/posts` image which is on my local! But since it was not updated, it doesn't do a thing!

Hence, what I should be doing was re-running `kubectl apply -f <my deployment filename>.yaml` again which already has been updated with the new image name as  `[my docker hub username]/microservices_posts`!

Then, I live happily ever after.
Hope that helps and may you live happily ever after too.

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach you can use if you have an image tag naming convention where you reuse/replace existing tags.

You'll want the container `imagePullPolicy: Always` to use this approach.

If there were **no changes** to your deployment yaml, but you simply need to pick up a **new** published image with the **same tag** (as is currently running), you can use the following -

```bash
kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment my-deployment-name

# then
kubectl scale --replicas=1 deployment my-deployment-name
# or
kubectl apply -f my-deployment-name.yaml
```

Just change your target replica count accordingly or reapply your original deployment yaml manifests.

You can also string these together -

```
kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment my-deployment-name && kubectl scale --replicas=1 deployment my-deployment-name
```